# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loc'

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to bucket the age values using a for loop as below

```
for dataset in train:
dataset.loc[(dataset['age'] > 15) & (dataset['age'] <= 25), 'age'] = 1
dataset.loc[(dataset['age'] > 25) & (dataset['age'] <= 35), 'age'] = 2
dataset.loc[(dataset['age'] > 35) & (dataset['Age'] <= 45), 'age'] = 3
dataset.loc[(dataset['age'] > 45) & (dataset['age'] <= 55), 'age'] = 4
dataset.loc[ dataset['age'] > 55, 'age']}
```

Getting error :

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

i am looking for my dataset to be like the one below:

```
age(in existing dataset)           age(in existing dataset)
25                                 1
35                                 2
45                                 3
73                                 4
```

Comment: can you show your `dataset` construction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe need omit loop, because if `train` is `DataFrame` then `dataset` are columns names, obviously `string`s:

```
np.random.seed(100)
train = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,3)), columns=['age','col1','col2'])
print (train)
   age  col1  col2
0    8     8     3
1    7     7     0
2    4     2     5

for dataset in train:
    print (dataset)

age
col1
col2
```

---

```
train.loc[(train['age'] > 15) & (train['age'] <= 25), 'new'] = 1
train.loc[(train['age'] > 25) & (train['age'] <= 35), 'new'] = 2
train.loc[(train['age'] > 35) & (train['age'] <= 45), 'new'] = 3
train.loc[(train['age'] > 45) & (train['age'] <= 55), 'new'] = 4
train.loc[ train['age'] > 55, 'new'] = 5
```

Better is use [`pd.cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
r = [0, 25, 35, 45, 55, 120]
g = [1,2,3,4,5]
train['new'] = pd.cut(train['age'], bins=r, labels=g)
```

Comment: Thank you so much i removed the loop and its working fine now

Answer (score 1):

It seems your dataset is a string, and a string does not have the attibute or method loc.
Check the type of your dataset with

```
type()
```

or

```
isinstance()
```

and see that it is the correct data type.

Answer (score 1):

#### Grouping ages into 3 categories:

- Child: 0-10
- Teen: 10-17
- Adult: 18-65
- Elderly: 65-110

```
r = [0,10,17,65, 110]
g = ['Child','Teen','Adult','Elderly']
train['AgeCtg'] = pd.cut(train['Age'], bins = r, labels = g)
```

### What we get is:

```
train.head(50)
```

[image: The expected output]

Answer (score 0):

just do this:

```
Train = [train]#converting the train dataframe into list

for dataset in Train:

dataset.loc[ dataset['Fare'] <= 17, 'Fare'] = 0, 

dataset.loc[(dataset['Fare'] > 17) & (dataset['Fare'] <= 30), 'Fare'] = 1, 

dataset.loc[(dataset['Fare'] > 30) & (dataset['Fare'] <= 100), 'Fare'] = 2, 

dataset.loc[ dataset['Fare'] > 100, 'Fare'] = 3
```

Comment: I had the same error, you can use this code above which worked for me very well or you can use pd.cut which is also an effective one. Thank you